# AG-Grid React: Does Row Spanning work when using cellRenderer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

When I use a custom cellRenderer in a row with rowspan=2, the content from the cellRenderer renders twice instead of once. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Row Spanning with Cell Renderers.

See the [following example](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/row-spanning/#example-row-spanning-complex) which has a Custom Cell Renderer. I'd have a look at this example and see how your application differs, since you've not provided a sample, it's not possible to see what the issue is on your end.

```
class ShowCellRenderer {
  init(params) {
    const cellBlank = !params.value;
    if (cellBlank) {
      return;
    }

    this.ui = document.createElement('div');
    this.ui.innerHTML =
      '<div class="show-name">' +
      params.value.name +
      '' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="show-presenter">' +
      params.value.presenter +
      '</div>';
  }

  getGui() {
    return this.ui;
  }

  refresh() {
    return false;
  }
}
```